# Why optional regular expression group is (only) sometimes None

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a regular expression in Python that has optional parts. I noticed that sometimes these optional parts match to None and sometimes they match to an empty string, or at least that is what it looks like from my testing. I would like to understand why and how to modify the regular expression to be consistently one way or the other.

```
def artifactory_url():
    test_input = [
        "https://www.domain.com/artifactory/my-root",
        "https://www.domain.com/artifactory",
        "https://www.domain.com/artifactory/my-root/platform",
        "http://www.domain.com/artifactory/my-root/platform",
        "http://www.domain.com/artifactory/my-root/platform/Daily Gold Reserve/WW3/bin",
        "single-dir",
        "double/dir",
    ]
    import re
    re_splitroot = re.compile('(?P<drive>https?://.+/artifactory)?/?(?:(?P<root>[^/]+)/?)?(?P<remainder>.*)?/?', re.IGNORECASE)
    for i in test_input:
        dprint (i)
        m = re_splitroot.match(i)
        if m:
            dprint (" True:\n  drive=%s\n  root=%s\n  remainder=%s" % (m.group('drive'), m.group('root'), m.group('remainder')), 0)
        else:
            dprint (" False")
```

This test function produces the following output.

```
https://www.domain.com/artifactory/my-root
 True:
  drive=https://www.domain.com/artifactory
  root=my-root
  remainder=
https://www.domain.com/artifactory
 True:
  drive=https://www.domain.com/artifactory
  root=None
  remainder=
https://www.domain.com/artifactory/my-root/platform
 True:
  drive=https://www.domain.com/artifactory
  root=my-root
  remainder=platform
http://www.domain.com/artifactory/my-root/platform
 True:
  drive=http://www.domain.com/artifactory
  root=my-root
  remainder=platform
http://www.domain.com/artifactory/my-root/platform/Daily Gold Reserve/WW3/bin
 True:
  drive=http://www.domain.com/artifactory
  root=my-root
  remainder=platform/Daily Gold Reserve/WW3/bin
single-dir
 True:
  drive=None
  root=single-dir
  remainder=
double/dir
 True:
  drive=None
  root=double
  remainder=dir
```

Comment: `(?:(?P<root>[^/]+)/?)?` => sometimes the outer one matches, sometimes not. I'd remove the `?:` if you want consistency. Or possibly make it: `(?P<root>[^/]*)/?` **edit:** That wouldn't explain about the drive being None or '' though....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first section:

```
(?P<drive>https?://.+/artifactory)?
```

should match any `http://.../artifactory` if it exists, but the trailing `?` means that if that is not found, the entire captured group will be empty.

You may want to use

```
(?P<drive>(?:https?://.+/artifactory)?)
```

Which will make that section capture "emptiness" if that match can't be found, but won't leave it NULL.

Your second section:

```
(?:(?P<root>[^/]+)\?)?
```

tries to capture anything that isn't a `/`, but the `(?:...)` group it's contained in has a trailing `?` making this also optional/empty. If you swap the `(?P<...>)` and `(?:...)` groups, your result will be more consistent to the first group.

Finally, your

```
(?P<remainder.*)?
```

group is redundant: It can capture 0-or-more remaining text with just the `.*` but then you make that optional (`?`) as well.  You can remove that `?` leaving you with an empty match.

Your example can be found on [this page](http://regex101.com/r/pB6wJ4/1), and the changes I suggested can be found on [this one](http://regex101.com/r/pB6wJ4/2), if you wanted to take a look and see if they yield any different results.